# Dividing a chart in two parts

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

I have the code of two graphs that I want to separate into two. I would like to see half of these results on one graph and the other half on another since the current plot contains too much information. Here is the code for my charts:

```r
    Medellin7 <- Medellin4 %>%
      filter(Medellin4$AÑO_T %in% c("2019"))
    Medellin7
    Medellin8 <- Medellin7 %>%
      filter(Medellin7$MES_TURNO %in% c("06"))
    Medellin8

    ATENCIONFUNCIONARIO <- Medellin8 %>%
      group_by(NOMBRE_SERVICIO, NOMBRE, NOMBRE_SERVICIO) %>%
      summarize(TIEMPO = mean(TIEMPO)) %>%
      ungroup() %>%
      mutate(NOMBRE_SERVICIO = factor(NOMBRE_SERVICIO, levels = unique(NOMBRE_SERVICIO)),
             NOMBRE = as.factor(NOMBRE))


  # First Chart  

    grafico5 <- ggplot(data = ATENCIONFUNCIONARIO, 
                       aes(x = NOMBRE_SERVICIO, y = TIEMPO, group = NOMBRE, colour = NOMBRE)) + 
      xlab("SERVICIO") + ylab("CANTIDAD") +
      ggtitle("TIEMPO PROMEDIO ATENCIÓN FUNCIONARIO")+
      theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1)) +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
      theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
            panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "white"))+  
      geom_line(lwd=1)
    grafico5


    Second Chart:

    FUNCIONARIO <- Medellin1 %>%
      group_by(AÑO_T, NOMBRE) %>%
      summarise(TIEMPO = length(TIEMPO))
    FUNCIONARIO <- FUNCIONARIO\[order(FUNCIONARIO$NOMBRE, decreasing = TRUE),\]

    M<- ggplot(FUNCIONARIO, aes(factor(NOMBRE), TIEMPO, fill = factor(AÑO_T))) + 
        geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")+
        theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1))+
        xlab("MES")+
        ylab("CANTIDAD")+
        labs(fill="AÑO")+
        ggtitle("DEMANDA MES")+
        theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
        theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "gray"))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Splitting the plot into two identical plots seems like a strange choice. One alternative would be to use `facet_wrap` using `Nombre` as the facet variable. This would give you a clear look at each line in the chart. Your code would look something like this:

```r
grafico5 <- ggplot(data = ATENCIONFUNCIONARIO, 
                       aes(x = NOMBRE_SERVICIO, y = TIEMPO)) + 
      xlab("SERVICIO") + ylab("CANTIDAD") +
      ggtitle("TIEMPO PROMEDIO ATENCIÓN FUNCIONARIO")+
      theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1)) +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
      theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
            panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "white"))+  
      geom_line(lwd=1) +
      facet_wrap(~Nombre)
```

Here's a reproducible example:

```r
data(iris)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Width, y=Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~Species)
```

Which gives you:

[image]